# How can I block POST requests to urls ending with /trackback/ in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm wanting to block POST requests to a specific URL on a website. Here is an example of a spammy POST request from my Apache log:

```
110.86.178.xxx - - [14/Jan/2015:17:05:05 +0000] "POST /profile/example/trackback/ HTTP/1.1" 200 85 "http://example.com/profile/example/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) )"
```

I added the following code to the .htaccess file:

```
# deny POST requests
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
    RewriteRule /profile/example/trackback/ [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately I'm still receiving trackback emails, so it's not working.

What is the issue and how can I fix this?
Also, how could I amend the code to block all POST requests sent to urls ending in /trackback/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule (^|/)trackback/?$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can block POST requests to any url ending with /trackback/ ?
For example:
http://example.com/example/profile/trackback/           ,    
http://example.com/trackback/               ,    
http://example.com/blog/trackback/

Comment: Yes sure, just change rule to: `RewriteRule /trackback/?$ [F,NC,L]`

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't. However, I changed the code slightly to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST` and then `RewriteRule ^trackback/?$ - [F,NC,L]` and it seems to have stopped the trackbacks so far.

Comment: ok answer updated for the correct regex of `any url ending with /trackback/ `.  you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
# deny all POST requests
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

More info [here](http://perishablepress.com/protect-post-requests/).

Comment: Thanks Mark. Forgive me, but doesn't this deny ALL post requests. Despite the comment I inadvertantly left in, I only want to block POST requests to a specific URL- and ideally to URLs ending with /trackback/

Comment: are you trying to block it in wordpress?

Comment: Yes, it is a WordPress website, but I am trying to block from the .htacess file.

Comment: Just remember that wordpress sometimes overwrites .htaccess file, so maybe it's better to put this into apache sites-available file.